# Django 1.3 performance

Tags: python, django, performance

As shown in "[Why Django Sucks](http://www.scribd.com/doc/37113340/Why-Django-Sucks-and-How-we-Can-Fix-it)" slides, Django slowed down significantly between 0.96 and 1.2.

Are there any tests measuring speed regression for 1.3 release?

Anyone here experienced any speed change (in both directions) with upgrade?

Comment: please add a link to the slides

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/37113340/Why-Django-Sucks-and-How-we-Can-Fix-it

Comment: "Illustrative only, take my numbers with a grain of salt".

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the code.

Comment: It sure is anecdotical, but shows trend and I have experienced higher load when moving from 1.0 to 1.1, so I'd like to know experiences of some other devs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have noticed no slow down in the django application itself while migrating a site from .9 to 1.3 on mysql. These slides may offer some useful criticisms, but the numbers don't seem to be useful at all.

In addition to django on mysql, I have been using django-nonrel based on 1.3 with mongodb and it is fast, I mean really fast, even with a table of 3 million records. Sorry no stats, but the database layer is still the bottleneck to be thinking about. And there are many ways to optimise the database layer in an app other than going with a nosql solution.

So, all I can say is django using normalized sql datbases is simple to set up, but slow in reality once you have more than 10's of thousands of records. Django with a nosql solution, or even just using mysql / postgresql with proper denormalization is fast.

There are so many good wsgi solutions available now too, that when taking into consideration stats like this, we really need to now what deployment solution is being tested. Consider these options - http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

Also consider in deployment, it is easy to have two front end web servers, or three. You hardly even need to change your conf. But scaling a database is much more difficult and requires a lot more thought and skill. So, Django being 10% slower for me is not really even an issue when you start comparing that in real numbers to your database latency.

Add in things like slave support for dbs, the option to configure db writes and reads, great apps like south, I could never reach the conclusion django sucks. Django 1.3 is rocking in my opinion.

Django could be better? Of course. Standardized tests would benefit Django? Of course. Is Django slow being a problem? No way.

Comment: We are having 5 frontends and ~600 rps in peaks. While speed issues are solvable, they are not exactly on our roadmap and if I am about to put more load on our servers, I would like to know it in advance and have to justify it.

Comment: @Almad It would be good to put that information to qualify the question as it seemed the question was more hypothetical. In the case you already have 5 frontends, maybe a good solution would be to run a test comparison of the different versions using your configuration with a tool like http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/